# why is num of map tasks get overriden?

Tags: hadoop

I configured a job in Hadoop and set the number of map tasks in my code to 8.
But when I run the job, 152 map tasks will be started.

I don't get why my configuration is being overriden and where the number 152 comes from.

For your reference: In my mapred-site.xml the value for "mapred.map.tasks" is 24.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum number of map tasks is set by Hadoop when it splits your data. You can't set the maximum below the minimum.

From the Hadoop wiki:

> The number of map tasks can also be increased manually using the JobConf's conf.setNumMapTasks(int num). This can be used to increase the number of map tasks, but will not set the number below that which Hadoop determines via splitting the input data.

Source: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces